# Solr multi core join with Spatial Search

Tags: solr

I have two cores customer and location. Following is sample data of customer core

```
[{"Name":abc,"Id":123},{"Name":xyz,"Id"354}]
```

and following is sample data of location core

```
[{"locationid":9834,"customerId":123,"lat_long_loc_s_i":"53.258496, -0.757421","active":True},
 {"locationid":9834,"customerId":354,"lat_long_loc_s_i":"53.258496, -0.757421","active":True},....
]
```

I want to search for the customers, who are living in 10 miles radius and active location.

The following query will give me the list of customers who have an active location

```
http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8983/solr/customer/select?q=*:*&fq={!join%20from=customerId%20to=Id%20fromIndex=location}active:True
```

How can I add spatial search on location core with an active filter to this

```
d=10&indent=on&pt=51.480401,%20-0.110252&sfield=lat_long_loc_s_i
```

if I add "&d=10...", it will apply query on customer core instead of location core.

(Solr version 7.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try as below, if this solves

I just used the *_p dynamic field for location, so modified the provided data.

Location data

[image]

Customer data

[image]

Joined data to filter records with d within 1000

[image]

Query:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/customer/select?q=*:*&fq={!join%20from=customerId%20to=Id%20fromIndex=location}active:true%20AND%20{!geofilt%20sfield=lat_long_loc_p}%20AND%20locationid:9836&d=800&indent=on&pt=52,0.5&sfield=lat_long_loc_p&debug=query
```